# Randomly positioning ordered points along line?

Tags: bayesian, prior

Assume that I have a line along which I want to randomly place (say) three points. If this were the only requirement, I could simply use independent uniform priors for all three points, and be done with it.

Unfortunately, I have the additional requirement that the points are positioned in a specific order: point one (blue) should always be the leftmost point, point three (green) should always be rightmost point, and point two (red) should always lie somewhere between (see sketch).

Ideally, I would like to position all three points with something close to a uniform prior, but a naive uniform pdf obviously does not fit the bill. I expect that generating random samples, then rejecting all which do not fit the criterion could work, but this seems very inelegant. Is there a more elegant way in which I could formulate a prior which represents this restriction?

[image]

Comment: What would be the problem with generating a random 3D variable $X=(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ according to any distribution you like, sorting the coordinates, and coloring the smallest blue, the middle red, and the rightmost green? This is not only simple, it's fully general.

Comment: None immediately, but if I were to employ variational methods (or some other technique which proposes changes to my samples), it could happen that my samples 'switch place', which I would like to avoid. I expect that one could avoid this with some form of sanity check (assigning zero probability density to reordered samples), but an analytic formulation might provide a more elegant solution.

Comment: I don't follow anything after "switch place," because that's not possible with the method I indicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the [stick-braking process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_process#The_stick-breaking_process). The story is as follows: imagine that we have a stick and we want to break it into $k$ parts. First you break it into two parts, leave one out, and break the latter again into two parts, repeating this $k-1$ times. Since you always break the remainder, the breakpoints would be ordered.

More formally, the algorithm is described by Frigyik et al (2010) in [*Introduction to the Dirichlet Distribution and Related Processes*](http://mayagupta.org/publications/FrigyikKapilaGuptaIntroToDirichlet.pdf):

> **Step 1:** Simulate $u_1 \sim \mathcal{B}(\alpha_1, \sum_{i=2}^k \alpha_i)$,  and  set $q_1=u_1$. This is the first piece of the stick.
>   The remaining piece has length $1-u_1$.
>   **Step 2:** For $2 \le j \le k-1$, if $j-1$ pieces, with lengths $u_1,u_2,\dots,u_{j-1}$, have been broken off, the length of the
>   remaining stick is $\prod_{i=1}^{j-1} (1-u_i)$.  We simulate $u_j
>  \sim \mathcal{B}(\alpha_j, \sum_{i=j+1}^k \alpha_i)$ and set $q_j =
>  u_j  \prod_{i=1}^{j-1} (1-u_i)$. The length of the remaining part of
>   the stick is $\prod_{i=1}^{j-1} (1-u_i) - u_j \prod_{i=1}^{j-1} (1 -
>  u_i) =\prod_{i=1}^j (1-u_i)$.
>
> **Step 3:** The length of the remaining piece is $q_k$.

This produces a sample from [Dirichlet distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/244917/what-exactly-is-the-alpha-in-the-dirichlet-distribution/244946#244946) $\mathbf{q} \sim \mathcal{D}(\boldsymbol{\alpha})$. If you want the distribution to be symmetric, you need $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=\dots=\alpha_k$. *Notice* that $q_i$'s are the *lengths* of the sticks, so to mark their borders, you need to take cumulated sum.

*Example code:*

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def stick(α):
    k = len(α)
    u = sp.beta(a=[α[i] for i in range(0, k-1)],
                b=[np.sum(α[i:]) for i in range(1, k)]).rvs(size=k-1)
    q = np.zeros(k)
    q[0] = u[0]
    for i in range(1, k-1):
        q[i] = u[i] * np.prod(1 - u[:i])
    q[k-1] = np.prod(1 - u[:k])
    return q

α = [10, 10, 10, 10]
n_sticks = 25

for s in range(n_sticks):
    q = stick(α)
    plt.bar(s, q[0], 1)
    for i in range(1, len(q)):
        plt.bar(s, q[i], 1, bottom=np.sum(q[:i]))

plt.axis('off')
plt.title(f'α = {α}')
plt.show()
```

[image]

You can manipulate the $\alpha_i$ values, for more details see [this answer on parameters of Dirichlet distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/244917/what-exactly-is-the-alpha-in-the-dirichlet-distribution/244946#244946).

*Of course, if you have more efficient algorithm for drawing samples from Dirichlet distribution, you can use it and just define the breakpoints as $b_j = \sum_{i=1}^j q_i$.*

Other solutions are simpler and computationally less demanding, but this is a stochastic process that you might find interesting, since it seems to share some of the properties of your data.

Comment: This sounds interesting, but it seems that if I were to repeat the experiment many times, the points would tend to cluster on one side of the stick (the one which I continue to 'break'). As such, it would not yield a quasi-uniform distribution. Am I misunderstanding this?

Comment: @J.Galt you can make it uniform when choosing the appropriate parameters, since this produces sample from Dirichlet distribution check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution#Marginal_beta_distributions or http://mayagupta.org/publications/FrigyikKapilaGuptaIntroToDirichlet.pdf for details.

Comment: @J.Galt my initial description might have been confusing, so I made edits to clarify and give example.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification! This does indeed do exactly what I wanted. I'll have to delve a bit deeper into the theory to form a solid foundation, but your answer provided a fantastic starting point. I'll mark this as the best answer.

Answer (score 3):

Why not generate a sample of three random points from a uniform distribution and then assign them the correct colors according to their order?

Comment: That... would actually be a surprisingly simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

My suggested method of meeting your specifications is shown in R code below.

Are your specifications consistent with three points chosen
at random without restriction on $(0,1)?$

```
set.seed(601)
b = runif(1); b
[1] 0.5592886
g = runif(1, b, 1); g
[1] 0.8007153
r = runif(1, b, g); r
[1] 0.7927287
plot(b, 0, col="blue", xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(-.1,.1), ylab="")
 points(g, 0, col="darkgreen")
 points(r, 0, col="red")
```

[image]

---

I think the answer to my question is No. Three unrestricted
points according to $\mathsf{Unif}(0,1)$ will have average range $E(\mathrm{Max - Min}) =1/2.$
Three points placed according to your restrictions, if I
understand the restrictions correctly, will have average range
$E(G - B) = 1/4.$ Here is a simulation. Formal proofs should
not be difficult.

```
set.seed(2020)
rng.u = replicate(10^6, diff(range(runif(3))))
mean(rng.u)
[1] 0.4997172

m = 10^6; rng.bgr = numeric(m)
for(i in 1:m){
 b = runif(1); g = runif(1, b, 1)
 rng.bgr[i] = g-b }
mean(rng.bgr)
[1] 0.2500847
```